# Calling objective c function from SWIFT through bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wamp-protocol

I have ported an objective-c package into a swift package and included it within the bridging header. Everything works fine, except there is a function I have to implement from a delegate I can't get working:

```
- (void) mdwamp:(MDWamp*)wamp sessionEstablished:(NSDictionary*)info;
```

Does anyone know how I can implement this in SWIFT?

Answer (score 1):

In the bridging header make sure you imported the objective-c header.

After doing that, you can use the following.

```
var instance: ClassName = ClassName()

instance.mdwamp(wamp, sessionEstablished: info)
```